# How to know, which process had accessed the harddrive last time and when?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, top

How to know, which process had accessed the harddrive last time and when?

Like `ntopng` with "last seen", but in local?

The question is about Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) which can show the list of process accessing Hard drive

[image]

Hope this helps.